# Elements are in wrong position on a 're-render' caused by unfiltering a filtered array

Tags: reactjs, masonry, redux, react-masonry

I am using [this react masonry component](https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component)

I am displaying my masonry tiles from a filtered array.

```
var myFilteredArray = myArray.filter( (tile) => this.props.filter.indexOf(tile.tag) > -1 )
var tiles = myFilteredArray.map( (tile) => <MyTile/>)
```

Where `myArray` is an array of json objects with a tag field. `props.filter` is an array of strings.

For example`props.filter` =  ["a","b","c"]  and the json tags are "a", "b", "c"

When I update my props filter so that props.filter = ["b"]

I see that the A and C objects disappear and object B moves to the left most of the container.

However when I add back tags "a" and "c" into props.filter, the objects show up in the wrong position. 
I would expect that the objects be in the order A,B,C, and filling up the container from the left most. What I see however is that object B goes back to where it was originally, and A, and C show up either on top of it or to the right of is. That means there is a big empty space to the left of Object B

My question is why is this happening? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide an example (perhaps via JSFiddle or JSBin) so we can better understand the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: If your not reordering the array elements prior to handing off to the masonry component, then it sounds like the output is just due to the components algorithm for where things are placed. Your probably going to have to dive into the components internals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @mattclemens suggested, it may be a problem with the algorithm for where things are placed.

It looks like this is already recorded here:
https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component/issues/11

The hacky solution is to put a dummy div first that has 1 width and 0 height in pixel (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hard to be sure without more info, but this smells like a list of components that are missing a key attribute. Try something like

```
var tiles = myFilteredArray.map( (tile) => <MyTile key={tile.tag}/>)
```

[Reference.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)